# Setting up text in a paragraph to automatically reference a number in a table from within a microsoft word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to set something up so that when I update numbers into a table within excel, it automatically updates that number in a paragraph that I am writing - similar to how you can set up fields to reference the document title or similar.

For example:
The number of cows in the field is ####

In a table elsewhere within the document I have:
Animal Type           Count
Dog                   20
Cow                   30

I want that XXXX to automatically update when I change the count of cows to 30. I think this has something to do with setting up the #### and the "30" as fields, but I can't find how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Link to the Excel cell.

Select the cell in Excel.

Edit->Copy (ctrl-C on Windows Word).

Click in the Word document where you want the value.

In the Home tab, Clipboard Group click the dropdown under "Paste" then click PasteSpecial...

Check the "Paste Link" box and select a suitable format - Unformatted Unicode Text, probably, then click OK.

You should see the value in the text. If you press Alt-F9 (Windows Word) you will see the field code that Word has inserted. It should look something like

```
{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "C:\\excel\\mywb\\Book1.xlsx" "Sheet1!R1C2" \a \t \u }
```

Press Alt-F9 again to see the result. Precisely *when* Word will update the value of the link depends on a number of factors, but when you modify the value of the Excel cell you will probably need to tab out of it, at least, and you may have to select the field and press F9 to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Within the same document, in Word:

In the table, highlight the source text and mark it as a bookmark

[image]

In the text, insert a REF field with the name of the bookmark.

{ REF cowcount}

Not sure about linking from an Excel file or an embedded Excel table.